# generate circular path with tikz and include empty node

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=1pt}]
  \node (1) at (8,6) {A1};
  \node (2) [below left of = 1] {A2};
  \node (3) [below right of = 2] {A3};
  \node (4) [below right of = 1] {A4};
  % True circle
  \draw[red, opacity=.3] ($(1)!.5!(3)$) circle (6.5mm);
  % connect the dots
  \path[->,>=stealth]
  (1) edge [bend right=20]  (2)
  (2) edge [bend right=20]  (3)
  (3) edge [bend right=20]  (4)
  (4) edge [bend right=20]  (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to generate the same diagram but without the node 'A1' i.e. I want the same shape but with an empty node the same size as A3 in the space where A1 would be. How can this be done?

Comment: you can mimic the size with `\phantom{A3}` in a node.

Comment: Or `[text opacity=0]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can mimic the content with

```
\node (3) [below right of = 2] {\phantom{A3}};
```

or for simple text, you can measure the text size and apply the dimensions to the node options

```
\node (3) [below right of = 2,minimum width={width("A3")},minimum height={height("A3")}] {};
```

or as Qrrbrbirlbel commented, you can avoid the text to be printed via setting the transparency to full transparent.

```
\node (3) [below right of = 2,text opacity=0] {A3};
```